# Is there a formal name for complexity in realistic cases?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Say, an algorithm has a theoretical time complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>). However, when it runs in some specific or realistic cases—for example, in the Facebook social graph each person cannot have more than 200 close friends (I know it’s not true, but let’s just assume that)—then its complexity is just linear O(n) due to some special characteristics of the input, even though theoretically it’s still O(n<sup>2</sup>).

I believe, I have seen a formal name for complexity of the algorithm in realistic cases, but can’t remember exactly what it is. It’s sorta “real complexity” or “realistic complexity” or something. Does anyone know if there is a special name for it? Or do I just happen to remember something from my dreams? :) I need it in my technical writing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there is a special name for such kind of complexity classes, since the performance of your algorithm strongly depends on the data distribution. However, the approach where you are estimating running time for some real world data has a name; it’s called [Smoothed Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed_analysis).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a formal name as far as I'm aware, but "**real-world** average/best/worst case complexity" would probably be understandable enough.

**Just for completeness:**

The *worst case* running time is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The *best case* running time is O(n).

We can't really say what the *average case* running time is from what is given.

[Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is an example of this. It runs in O(n) when the data is already sorted, but runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the average / worst case.

Comment: I am aware of worst case and best case :). But wonder if there is a name, something like "realistic complexity" or something. I kinda saw it in a paper I read in the past.

Comment: Not a formal name as far as I'm aware, but "real-world average/best/worst case complexity" would probably be understandable enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer for this would be *average case*. Your average is computed as the weighted mean over the probability of the input, so if an algorithm has complexity `a * n + b` for input `I1` and `c * n^2 + d * n + e` for input `I2`, its average complexity will be:

```
AC = p * (a * n + b) + (1 - p) * (c * n^2 + d * n + e)
```

Where `p` is the probability of input being `I1`. If in real cases, input is *almost always* `I1` (i.e. `p = 1`) then your average complexity will be O(n). Academic proofs tend to assume a uniform distribution for the inputs (all inputs have the same probability of happening, `p = 1/2` in my example), but to study the complexity of an algorithm in the 'real world', you have to estimate the actual probability of occurrence of the inputs, and this might change the average complexity of your algorithm (although it usually doesn't: in the example, even if `p = 0.99999`, the average complexity would still be O(n^2), although the factors would be changed).

If you *assume* that no one ever has more than 200 friends, you implicitly set the probability of `nb_friends > 200` to 0, which changes your average complexity even though best-case and worst-case are unchanged.